# Mysql join query help to show 2 seperate records

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have this query which returns the courses which has `status = "offering"` and `offered by that user` who also has a course with the `courseid "3"` now the **problem** is that

There is a sc_c_material table that has 2 records against a course i want to show 2 seperate rows against this, where 1 row has sc_course data with 1st record of sc_c_material and 2nd row again with sc_course data with 2nd record of sc_c_material

The below query `only return 1 record` for the course which has `id 9` where `id 9` has `2 records` in `sc_c_materials` table. i want both of those record from `sc_c_material` table

I hope I have cleared my point, because it was a bit hard to explain

```
SELECT c.`id`,
     c.`coursecode`,
     m.`title`,
     a.`author_name`,
     q.`quality`,
     m.`comments`,
     s.status,
     u.id,
     m.`material`
FROM sc_courses c,
     sc_status s,
     sc_c_materials m, 
     sc_authors a,
     sc_quality q,
     users u
WHERE c.`statusid`=s.`id`
    AND c.`userid`=u.`id`
    AND m.`qualityid`=q.`id`
    AND m.`authorid`=a.`id`
    AND c.`id`=m.`courseid`
    AND s.`status`="offering"
    AND c.`userid` IN (SELECT userid 
                FROM sc_courses 
                WHERE id="3" 
                GROUP BY userid)
```

Comment: Can you provide the example result set and your desired result set

Comment: Blah, blah, blah, this is all great because it shows us that you're making an effort, but now just show us some data (DDLs/sqlfiddle) AND THE DESIRED RESULT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would start by using ANSI SQL-92 style queries where you show the join relations instead of bulking them all in the where clause.  It gives better visualization on how table X is related to table Y (although your SQL-89 format still works).  Also, you should only need the tic ` marks around fields that might cause a problem due to reserved words that are also column names.

The underlying query SHOULD work, however, by looking at the join conditions, I am seeing that the materials table is joined to BOTH the authors and quality tables.  If there is a missing / invalid ID relationship to either of the tables, then only one record will be returned.  In that case, I have changed to a LEFT-JOIN to see if that really is the case

```
SELECT 
      c.id,
      c.coursecode,
      m.`title`,
      a.author_name,
      q.quality,
      m.comments,
      s.status,
      u.id,
      m.material
   FROM 
      sc_courses c
         JOIN sc_status s
            ON c.statusid = s.id
           AND s.status= 'offering'

         JOIN sc_c_materials m
            ON c.id= m.courseid

            LEFT JOIN sc_authors a
               ON m.authorid = a.id
            LEFT JOIN sc_quality q
               ON m.qualityid = q.id

         JOIN users u
            ON c.userid = u.id
   WHERE
      c.userid IN (SELECT userid 
                FROM sc_courses 
                WHERE id='3'
                GROUP BY userid)
```

The LEFT-JOIN means I want everything from the LEFT table that is listed first within the from table clause... in this case sc_c_materials (in relation to the authors and quality) REGARDLESS of actually finding the match in the authors or quality tables.  So, during such not-found elements in those other tables, any columns you may attempt to pull from them would come back as NULL.

Since you originally had an implied INNER JOIN (all your criteria in the where clause directly), your query was telling the engine... I only want records that exist where all pieces are found, so it was ignoring the record that did not have the match in whichever table was missing the link.

Comment: man ur genious, it works! thank you so much! but can u explain it a little bit... why we used left join on author and quality only... how does it makes a difference?